# How to check whether an email address exists?

Tags: email

I'm trying to check 2,000 email addresses to see whether they exist. Are there ways to check whether an email address is valid without sending email to each address?.

I found an online service [Email Unlimited](http://www.email-unlimited.com/), but it only checks 20 email addresses before having to buy the full version.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness: **some** SMTP servers *do* indicate if an email address exists. Following a full example [in another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/207926/if-to-and-from-headers-are-the-spammers-email-address-how-did-i-get-this-em/208156#208156):

> `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`
>
> `helo example.com`
> `mail from: <me@example.com>`
> `rcpt to: <somenonexistinguser@gmail.com>`
> <sub>`550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try`
>
> `550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or`
>
> `550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at`
>
> `550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596`</sub>

Upon success, and on servers that cannot or do not want to tell if an address is valid, the last command would yield:

> <sub>`250 2.1.5 OK`</sub>

One could then simply invoke `quit` without sending any email at all. Still, when trying many addresses, this might also get you blocked.

(Gmail does not support the `vrfy` command. On the website, it also has a "check availability" button when [signing up](https://www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount?service=mail) for a new Gmail account. That could also give you *some* information, but old addresses will be unavailable for some time.)

Comment: SMTP defines the `VRFY` command for this purpose.

Comment: @grawity, that might be true in theory, but `VRFY` does NOT work with Gmail. (See my comment [at Michael's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/224015/how-to-check-if-email-address-does-exist/224023#224023).)

Comment: Not all servers respond with a "does not exist" error for missing accounts, so this is not completely reliable. If the server is an proxy (and/or external secondary server) for a number of other servers it might not know which accounts are valid on the next hop so will give "250 OK" for anything, and some servers are set this way in to stop spammers trying to enumerate valid accounts. A quick test of some of our clients mail servers showed 1 of the 5 I tried did not give a 5xx response for an non-existent account.

Comment: (@David, I know. That's why I used the word "some" above... But I've emphasised that a bit.)

Comment: @Arjan I wrote a small python script to automate this https://gist.github.com/arulrajnet/c613bd0fad5de00bab2e

Comment: First test an address that is unlikely to exist (e.g. `uh57fxetomx7ei5@example.com`), if that returns `250`, give up.

Comment: Try this Perl module here https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ILYAM/Mail-CheckUser-1.19/CheckUser.pm

Answer (score 23):

If this were possible, spammers worldwide would be singing with joy.

Sorry but **no, it's not possible to know whether any given e-mail address exists or not.**

In my opinion, this is a feature!

- If you **know** your correspondents, then you will know their contact information.
- If you **don't know** your correspondents, then you're a stranger and they will not appreciate getting unsolicited mail from you.
- If you **used to know** your correspondents and they haven't kept you informed of their address changes, then they've made an (un?)conscious decision to not receive your mail.

The best you can do is to send out an e-mail to your list and then remove those that bounce (= those that could not be delivered).

Be careful! In some countries it is illegal to send unsolicited bulk e-mail to people who haven't explicitly allowed this in advance.

Comment: Thanks for this. But yes, we know the contacts but some of them didn't update their contact details with us when they changed positions or companies. We sent out newsletter last time and it bounces back email addresses and our account was reactivated because of the high percentage of the bounces of emails. I found one in the internet but not sure if this is reliable: http://verify-email.org/

Comment: +1 - if it worked it would quickly be abused. This is why we can't have nice things!

Comment: Not sure why this is strongly upvoted. The ethics 101 lesson?  I've seen something like what the OP wants being used, and not even for nefarious purposes. The other answers and comments suggest it's possible for many mail servers, especially corporate/non-Google.

Comment: @Daniel: it is certainly *possible* for *some* (*many*, in fact) mail servers/services - but it is not reliably possible nor is is necessarily reliable for any given address. I up-voted for the technical correctness of "you can't know for sure" rather than any ethical aspect.

Comment: People who were used as the fake sender of spam runs, won't be too happy about this "feature" when receiving lots of [backscatter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_%28e-mail%29). (Apart from the occasional bounce message from runs that use a different `From`, `Reply-to` or `Return-Path` for each message, I've received thousands of bounce messages on two occasions. Easily filtered, still not very nice.)

Comment: @tintincute: I think the information you're looking for is in the bounces you received from your last newsletter.

Comment: It is possible to at least partially check if the email address does _not_ exist by checking if the domain of the email address exists -- if the domain does not exist, the email address is currently invalid and there is no need to check that email address further (at least temporarily).

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/224015/how-to-check-if-email-address-does-exist - looks very real to me.

Comment: I can definitely appreciate your answer as nobody likes spam, but this is not always true; just sayin'. For example, Gmail keeps a record of anyone you've ever emailed or who has emailed you. I have contact details for many classmates from my college days and would like to validate their emails to determine whether I should hold on to their contacts or delete them. This would be a perfectly legitimate use for this kind of functionality. ;)

Comment: This is not true. You can find hundreds of free or subscription services online to (bulk)check validity of email addresses.

Comment: @wideseen - those services don't actually check the recipient mailboxes; they compare the requested data against their internal records. If you ask me if bob@example.com is a valid address, then I will look in my address book or logs from past mailings. If I ever sent anything to Bob, and my mails didn't bounce, then I will answer that yes, that's a valid address - but that's just based on historical data. I won't know whether the mailbox has since been deleted.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Then where do the mail-check app providers find the history? They cannot look in their own address book of logs from past mailings for any email-address you throw at them.

Comment: @wideseen I am not in that business but it is no secret that lists of (ostensibly valid) email addresses are bought and sold.

Comment: Then this has to be a scam and the services listed: https://clean.email/verifier/how-to-check-if-an-email-is-valid
Please convince me.

Answer (score 7):

There really isn't any good way to do so. There is a 'VRFY' command in the SMTP protocol, but I don't know anyone who lets that operate anymore - it's too useful to spammers. Most hosts will just refuse the command anymore.

The best you can do right now is to send the e-mail and record what bounces (noting that some mail hosts will just blackhole undeliverable mail instead of bouncing it).

I don't know what your business or purpose is with this list, but you should know that if you go sending e-mail to 2000 people at once, you're likely to get flagged as a spammer by some mail hosts.

Comment: Probably more like clearing out a contact list. Mails bounce anyway.

Comment: Trying to clean out the contacts; I need to design a new contacts database. We have a lot of clients from different companies, not sure if I have to categorize them in one database or would create a different DB for different companies. What would be the best way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, then `vrfy` [would need a username](http://the-welters.com/professional/smtp.html), not an email address? If true, then I guess it's mainly being disabled for security reasons, not to combat spammers? On Gmail, both `vrfy existinguser`, `vrfy existinguser@gmail.com`, `vrfy someunknownuser` and `vrfy someunknownuser@gmail.com` all yield `252 2.1.5 Send some mail, I'll try my best`, while on the very same Gmail `rcpt to:` *does* reveal if an email address is valid.

Comment: With vrfy, you connect to a mail server, then vrfy username (the part before the @ in the e-mail address). If it's working, it will tell you yes or no whether the user is real. If it's not working (many are not) then it will either say 'forbidden', or 'I have no idea'. Note that the 'I have no idea' answer is perfectly legitimate for a mail forwarding host that doesn't have access to the underly account list. So even when working, vrfy may not be that useful.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to accurately determin if an address is real or not - any product that claims it can is exagerating its abilities so you shoudl consider any other claims made with a cynical eye.

There are in existence F/OSS libraries that do as much as it is possible to do: I would guess that most software on the market is just a fancy wrapper around those so you could perhaps easily make your own that is just as good/bad if you have any coding experience. But remember that no matter how good the validation routine is it will be very prone to give both false positive and false negative results.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/emailaddressvalidationcomponent for example comes up on a quick search fo freshmeat and assuming the description is correct it does everything that can actually be done to try verify an address.

Comment: @DanieL: Ok thanks for this. How about this one? Is this also valid: http://techie-buzz.com/how-to/how-to-verify-if-an-email-address-exists.html

Comment: @tintincute: looks pretty valid, my Lifehacker source uses the same video...

Answer (score 2):

You can **ping** the email address.

From Lifehacker.com:

> http://lifehacker.com/5697360/how-to-verify-if-an-email-address-is-real-or-fake
>
> When you send an email to someone, the message goes to an SMTP server which then looks for the MX (Mail Exchange) records of the email recipient's domain.

Hit the link for step-by-step instructions on how to ping an email address.

Answer (score 1):

Inside a company context, this could be done by automating a lookups in Active directory.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing a Perl script to automate this job?
Check this out: http://search.cpan.org/~ilyam/Mail-CheckUser-1.21/CheckUser.pm

Comment: This actually uses SMTP commands to connect to an SMTP server, and if you make too many requests too soon you could be labeled as a spammer and blocked. So, not good for checking thousands of emails.

Answer (score 1):

I also needed a way to verify the existence of email addresses, so I ended up writing my own little utility. (Python)

http://github.com/un33k/python-emailahoy

It is 100% accurate when the provider is honest with you.
(gmail is pretty honest, but yahoo is NOT as it says yes to all emails.)

It is better than nothing, as it reduced the spams by more than %50 for me.

Comment: A test with my own email adress shows that a mail is actually sent during the test, something which should be documented.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to check whether an email address exists by using this link:
http://verify-email.org/. It pings the email address and responds `Ok` if the email exists, and `Bad` if the email is fake or does not exist.
one more link helpful for this problem:
http://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-verify-if-email-address-exist-or-not.html

Comment: 1st link: it looks like checking single addresses is free, but checking 2000, as asked in the question, requires paid software. That's the situation for which the question seeks an alternative, so this isn't really a solution to the question.  2nd link also deals with single checks.  Super User isn't a forum, where it is typical to leave anything that generally relates to the topic.  Its purpose is to build a knowledgebase, and each answer should provide a solution to what was asked.  Answers that don't tend to attract downvotes.