# Can an email delivery silently fail?

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

Can an email delivery silently fail ever, with the sender receiving no notification whatsoever about the failed delivery?

Specifically, can silent delivery failures occur for mail sent to a Gmail account:

1. From another Gmail account?
2. From a non-Gmail account?

I once in a while hear some people complain about not receiving my email, especially when I follow up on the email contents with them over phone. At that point they ask me to try resending.

Doesn't the SMTP protocol guarantee email delivery, or at least a failed delivery notification to the sender?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Doesn't the SMTP protocol guarantee email delivery, or at least a
> failed delivery notification to the sender?

No, [SMTP has no delivery guarantees](https://serverfault.com/questions/308952/if-e-mail-is-only-best-effort-delivery-is-there-a-similar-protocol-with-guara) (you can check it yourself in [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)):

> There are mechanisms glued on to the SMTP protocol and associated
> programs for ensuring delivery (DSN, Return Receipts). Note that these
> themselves are best-effort / mutual cooperation extensions (Most mail
> clients let you elect not to send read receipts, and some clients
> can't issue a read receipt. Some MTAs can't/won't issue a delivery
> receipt.

...

> Specifically, can silent delivery failures occur for mail sent to a
> Gmail account.

Yes, but that's quite unlikely, Google has excessive infrastructure and usually handles it's data well.

> I once in a while hear some people complain about not receiving my
> email, especially when I follow up on the email contents with them
> over phone.

- It could be just a polite way to say that they didn't have time\opportunity to read it.

**or**

- Your phone's internet connection is not reliable and fails silently or your operator filters\blocks your traffic (i.e.: [Verizon faces lawsuit over email blocking](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2005/01/21/verizon_class_action)).

Comment: It is quite common for organizations to have spam filters which expressly ditch the message silently. In some situations, generating bounce messages is prone to abuse; look up "blowback" or ["backscatter"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email))

Answer (score 2):

SMTP does not require a bounce back, although it appears [Gmail might do it:](https://superuser.com/questions/224015/how-to-check-if-email-address-does-exist)

There is risk involved with showing what responses a server gives although the bounceback is generally considered enough of a benefit to overlook the risk.

Simple fact of it is: most "undelivered" emails are in one of Gmails folders (In my case I have two Spam folders, one called Spam and one called Junk)